# 'tree' command on databricks /dbfs

Tags: bash, databricks

I'd like to find out file size statistics on /dbfs (databricks file system)

I attempted to run 'tree' via notebook like below

```
%sh

tree --du -h | grep "G]"
```

the error says there is no 'tree' command installed.
`/bin/bash: tree: command not found`

can you please help how i can get the result? how to install the 'tree' or any command equivalent in dbfs utils?

I do not want to do 'ls' which will be too slow.

Comment: `ls -rlh`? `du -h`?

Answer (score 1):

Use of `tree` won't help you if `ls` is too slow for you - when you list `/dbfs/` it needs to go to the cloud storage and perform list operations anyway, so there should be no difference in the performance.  The reason for that is that DBFS is just an abstraction over the specific cloud storage.

If you want to get detailed file information, then it's better to use cloud native tool, like, `aws s3`, `az storage`, etc.

Comment: My motive is to find the file size statistics for the “ azure managed resource group-storage account created by azure databricks”

Comment: I would still recommend to try to use `dbutils.fs.ls` or even code that uses Hadoop API. But you can also install `tree` with `%sh apt-get install tree`, although as I wrote, it will be slow anyway

Comment: Also I assumed ``ls will be slow, so I did not even try. 
I am not sure I can use azure cli stirage against the databricks_**** managed resource group

Comment: yes, unfortunately you can't use azure cli against managed resource group. Scalable listing is the problem - Hadoop still doesn't support recursive listing for Azure :-(

Comment: When I worked on cloudera/mapR in house , I think we could use ` hdfs du`

Comment: you can still use Hadoop APIs, but overall listing stuff is different in the cloud